# How to set an instance of a model as an attribute of another model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, instance

I am fairly new to Rails and working on an app that will allow a user to make a `List` containing their top 5 `Item`s of a certain category.  The main issue I'm having is how to keep track of the `List` order (which should be allowed to change and will be different for each `User`)?

My `Item`s can belong to many `List`s and my `List`s should have many `Item`s so, as of now, I am using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for both my `Item` and `List` models.

My idea to keep track of the list order right now is to have my `@list` have 5 attributes: one for each ranking on the list (ie. `:first, :second, :third, :fourth, :fifth`) and I am attempting to associate the `@item` instance to the @list attribute (ie. `@list.first = @item1, @list.second = @item2` , etc...).  Right now I am saving the `@list` attribute to the `@item` ID (`@list.first = 1`), but I would prefer to be able to call the method `.first` or `.second` etc and have that point directly at the specific `Item` instance.

Here is my current schema for `lists`, `items`, and the join table `list_nominations` required for the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association-which I'm pretty sure I am not utilizing correctly (the `:points` attribute in `items` will be a way of keeping track of popularity of an `item`:

```
create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "first"
    t.string "second"
    t.string "third"
    t.string "fourth"
    t.string "fifth"
  end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "points", default: 0
  end
```

and here is the code currently in my `List` and `Item` models:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
```

Is there a way to do this or any suggestions on a better way to keep track of the `List` order without creating multiple instances of the same `Item`?

Comment: hello, can you please share the code inside the model and their schema?

Comment: Just added the model and schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your tables don't fit any known approach, you can achieve what you want but this is not a perfect **nor a recommended** solution, you could specify the primary key on many has_one associations inside `lists` but in `items` it's not very possible to have all `lists` in one association but you can have an instance method which query `lists` and returns the matched ones

the hacky solution:

```rb
class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :category

    has_one :first_item, primary_key: :first, class_name: "Item"
    has_one :second_item, primary_key: :second, class_name: "Item"
    has_one :third_item, primary_key: :third, class_name: "Item"
    has_one :fourth_item, primary_key: :fourth, class_name: "Item"
    has_one :fifth_item, primary_key: :fifth, class_name: "Item"
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category

    def lists
        List.where(
            "first = ? OR second = ? OR third = ? OR fourth = ? OR fifth = ?", self.id, self.id, self.id, self.id, self.id
        )
    end
end
```

you can read about how to create a many-to-many relationship via `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association (your tables will need a field to properly point to each other)

## What I recommend doing is following a `many-to-many through` relationship guide (mono-transitive association) :

you will need 1 extra table because you want to track the order(first,second, etc)

DB:

```rb
create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    .. all your other fields without first,second, etc..
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    .. all your other fields
end

create_table "lists_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.integer "item_id"
    t.integer "rank" there is where you will store your order (first, second ..) bas as an integer
end
```

Models:

```rb
class ListsItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :list
    belongs_to :item
end

class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :lists_items, -> { order(:rank) }, limit: 5
    has_many :items, through: :lists_items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :lists_items
    has_many :lists, through: :lists_items
end
```

you can read more about many-to-many via has_many through here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

and the difference between the 2 approaches here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: This is great.  Thanks!  Was able to refactor to incorporate the way you recommended and it is much cleaner and works the way I need it to.  My list#create action seems a little bloated as I'm not sure if there is an easy way to associate both the `item` and its `rank` to the `list` all at once.  But for now, I'll take it.  Thanks again!